# Coverting DateTime property to string format from List ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my ASP.NET MVC web application Im assigning some data from the database to a list.

There in the database example like `start_date` is stored as `DateTime` property.

So when it comes to the view, I just want to show the `dd mmm yyyy` format.

What I currently did was, I got all the data I wanted from the database and again used foreach condition and converted the DateTime to string to another property I created on the model.

It worked when there was one record to show. But when It comes to the list, it applied to the first record only. Others becomes null.

Can anyone suggest a better solution for this.

This is my current code

```
IEnumerable < MyTasks > myTasks = (from t in db.TaskMain 
                                    join c in db.Customer on t.Customer_Id equals c.Id 
                                    join s in db.Services on t.Service_Id equals s.Id 
                                    join step in db.ServiceSteps on t.Task_Step_Id equals step.Id 
                                    join state in db.ServiceState on t.Task_State_Id equals state.Id 
                                    where t.CreateBy == UserId && t.Status == true && t.Task_Step_Id != 12 
                                    select new MyTasks 
                                    {
                                        Id = t.Id,
                                        Customer_Name = c.Name,
                                        Service = s.Service_NameEng,
                                        Current_Step = step.Service_Step_Primary_Language,
                                        End_Date = t.Service_End_Date,
                                        Start_Date = t.CreatedDate,
                                        Task_Number = t.TaskNumber,
                                        Task_State = state.Service_State_Name
                                    }).ToList();

foreach(var item in myTasks) 
    {
        myTasks.First().Start_Date_Formated = item.Start_Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
        myTasks.First().End_Date_Formated = item.End_Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
    }
```

This is the result

[image]

Comment: When you debug and look at it, does it show as empty? `IEnumerable < MyTasks > myTasks`

Comment: `myTasks.First()` only pulls the first record. so you should just use `item.Start_Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")` where you want to show

Answer (score 0):

you just need to select the format you wanted like this

```
  IEnumerable<MyTasks> myTasks = (from t in db.TaskMain
                                        join c in db.Customer on t.Customer_Id equals c.Id
                                        join s in db.Services on t.Service_Id equals s.Id
                                        join step in db.ServiceSteps on t.Task_Step_Id equals step.Id
                                        join state in db.ServiceState on t.Task_State_Id equals state.Id
                                        where t.CreateBy == UserId && t.Status == true && t.Task_Step_Id != 12
                                        select new MyTasks
                                        {
                                            Id = t.Id,
                                            Customer_Name = c.Name,
                                            Service = s.Service_NameEng,
                                    End_Date = t.Service_End_Date,
                                    Start_Date = t.CreatedDate,
                                            Current_Step = step.Service_Step_Primary_Language,
                                            End_Date_Formated = t.Service_End_Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"),
                                            Start_Date_Formated = t.CreatedDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"),
                                            Task_Number = t.TaskNumber,
                                            Task_State = state.Service_State_Name
                                        }).ToList();
```

but if the dates is nullable value then you need to check so the code become like this

```
   IEnumerable<MyTasks> myTasks = (from t in db.TaskMain
                                    join c in db.Customer on t.Customer_Id equals c.Id
                                    join s in db.Services on t.Service_Id equals s.Id
                                    join step in db.ServiceSteps on t.Task_Step_Id equals step.Id
                                    join state in db.ServiceState on t.Task_State_Id equals state.Id
                                    where t.CreateBy == UserId && t.Status == true && t.Task_Step_Id != 12
                                    select new MyTasks
                                    {
                                        Id = t.Id,
                                        Customer_Name = c.Name,
                                        Service = s.Service_NameEng,
                                    End_Date = t.Service_End_Date,
                                    Start_Date = t.CreatedDate,
                                        Current_Step = step.Service_Step_Primary_Language,
                                        End_Date_Formated = t.Service_End_Date==null? null: t.Service_End_Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"),
                                        Start_Date_Formated = t.CreatedDate==null?null: t.CreatedDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"),
                                        Task_Number = t.TaskNumber,
                                        Task_State = state.Service_State_Name
                                    }).ToList();
```

and you can set a default value for the date if it is null like "N/A"

```
 End_Date_Formated = t.Service_End_Date == null ? "N/A" : t.Service_End_Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"),
 Start_Date_Formated = t.CreatedDate == null ? "N/A" : t.CreatedDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"),
```

But you should comment this code as it only changes the first object and after the loop ends you will find that it takes its value from last item on the "myTasks"

```
 //foreach (var item in myTasks)
        //{
        //    myTasks.First().Start_Date_Formated = item.Start_Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
        //    myTasks.First().End_Date_Formated = item.End_Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
        //}
```